# React Loop through array and render

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, render

I am trying to display both of these arrays. Everytime you click the button a new user is generated and I added to the array. I would like for it to render the entire array and not only the newest lines. I have tried many things. I keep seeing online about mapping but I can not get any of that to work correctly.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import $ from "jquery";

var personlist = [];
var imglist = [];
var i = 0;

class People extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "firstlastname",
      image: "image"
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    getUser = () => {
      var usersname;
      var thumbnail;

      $.ajax({
        url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=name,picture",
        data: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
          usersname = JSON.stringify(
            data.results[0].name.first + " " + data.results[0].name.last
          );

          thumbnail = JSON.stringify(data.results[0].picture.thumbnail);

          newUser = usersname;
          newImage = thumbnail;

          var eventstring = new String(); //remove quotes from image string
          eventstring = newImage.toString().replace(/"/g, ""); //remove quotes from image string

          personlist.push([newUser, eventstring]);
          imglist.push([eventstring]);
          console.log(personlist);
        },

        error: function (errormsg) {
          console.log(errormsg);
        }
      });
    };

    this.getUser();

    var eventstring = new String(); //remove quotes from image string
    eventstring = newImage.toString().replace(/"/g, ""); //remove quotes from image string

    return { name: newUser, image: eventstring };
  }

  changeColor = () => {
    //change state to rerender
    this.setState({ name: "updt" });
    i++;
    return { name: "updt" };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.changeColor}>Generate New Person</button>

        <div>
          
          <h1>{personlist[i][0]}</h1>
          <img src={personlist[i][1]} alt="none" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default People;
```

Comment: First you have to understand about the react component that if you want to store something like the results you get from fetch, you can store it in the component's state, not in a variable outside the state. From the looks of it you don't know about React components or class based components.

Comment: Also, if you want to render all users in the array, you have to explicitly define this in the render function. Please read up about the concept of JSX and how you could achieve such functionality using the `Array.map()`.

Answer (score 0):

React components can store data in their state variable and in classes, you can access the state using `this.state` and if you want to modify the state, you can use `this.setState` function. You can read more on the react site.

Below is the refactored code you provided where I've initialized the `people` array in the state. And in the `fetchPerson` method, you can see it after fetching the data, it calls `this.setState` method to update the current state which will cause the component to re-render. I've replaced the `changeColor` method to `onGetNewPerson` which you used to render the component in order to get a new person. In the render method, you can see I am using the `map` function which is available to arrays, you can read more about this in the Mozilla Javascript documentation. If you don't know about classes, you can check about functional components.

```
class People extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "firstlastname",
      image: "image",
      people: [],
    };

    this.onGetNewPerson = this.onGetNewPerson.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPerson();
  }

  fetchPerson() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=name,picture",
      data: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function (data) {
        // if you want to replace the people array in the state
        // this.setState({ people: data.results });

        // if you want to append to the people array
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return {
            people: prevState.people.concat(data.results)
          };
        });
      }
    });
  }

  parsePerson(person) {
    const name = JSON.stringify(
      person.name.first + " " + person.name.last
    );
    const image = JSON.stringify(person.picture.thumbnail).toString().replace(/"/g, "");

    return { name, image };
  }

  onGetNewPerson = () => {
    // on click => fetch and append new person
    this.fetchPerson();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onGetNewPerson}>Generate New Person</button>

        <div>
          {this.state.people.map((person, i) => {
            const p = this.parsePerson(person);
            return (
              <div key={"person-" + i}>
                <h1>{p.name}</h1>
                <img src={p.image} alt="none" />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```